# Get a list of dynamic names from a DB and have a cron job that traverses this array (php)

Tags: php, cron, wait

Here's what I'm trying to accomplish in high-level pseudocode:

```
query db for a list of names (~100)
for each name (using php) {
    query a 3rd party site for xml based on the name
    parse/trim the data received
    update my db with this data
    Wait 15 seconds (the 3rd party site has restrictions and I can only make 4 queries / minute)
}
```

So this was running fine. The whole script took ~25 minutes (99% of the time was spent waiting 15 seconds after every iteration). My web host then made a change so that scripts will timeout after 70 seconds (understandable). This completely breaks my script.

I assume I need to use cronjobs or command line to accomplish this. I only understand the basic us of cronjobs. Any high level advice on how to split up this work in a cronjob? I am not sure how a cronjob could parse through a dynamic list.

Answer (score 0):

cron itself has no idea of your list and what is done already, but you can use two kinds of cron-jobs.

The first cron-job - that runs for example once a day - could add your 100 items to a job queue.

The second cron-job - that runs for example once every minute in a certain period - can check if there are items in the queue, execute one (or a few) and remove it from the queue.

Note that both cron-jobs are just triggers to start a php script in this case and you have two different scripts, one to set the queue and one to process part of a queue so almost everything is still done in php.

Comment: I understand the theory and this would be nice to be automated like this. The part I'm missing is how the 2 cron jobs would would be able to have access to the shared data. Would I need another db table to store this queue or is there some easier way?

Comment: @johnpecan Personally I would use a database, but you could use a file I guess. It's just two different php scripts connecting to the same queue / database / file to do the processing. And instead of a browser you use cron to run them.

Answer (score 0):

In short, there is not much that is different. Instead of executing the script via modphp or fcgi, you are going to execute it via command line `php /path/to/script.php`.

Because this is a different environment than http, some things obviously don't work. Sessions, cookies, get and post variables. Output gets send to stdout instead of the browser.

You can pass arguments to your script by using `$argv`.

Comment: I think this makes sense and for my situation. I will try this this evening.